# How To Reset Time In DateTime Column Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to convert date time field to date only, but when I do that the dtype changed to object, so I'm thinking to reset all time in all rows to be zeros

from

```
                     Price  Volume
2011-08-14 14:14:40   10.4   0.779
2011-08-14 15:15:17   10.4   0.101
2011-08-14 15:15:17   10.4   0.316
2011-08-14 16:45:09   10.5   0.150
2011-08-14 16:45:09   10.5   1.800
```

to

```
                     Price  Volume
2011-08-14 00:00:00   10.4   0.779
2011-08-14 00:00:00   10.4   0.101
2011-08-14 00:00:00   10.4   0.316
2011-08-14 00:00:00   10.5   0.150
2011-08-14 00:00:00   10.5   1.800
```

how can I do that ?

many thanks

Comment: Why not get rid of time component completely?

Comment: because its dtype changed to object and I need this to build a plot date based